Similar Component in Bootstrap
I'm building a website based on Bootstrap 5.3.3. And I'm looking for a component similar to the one attached in the photo.  I prefer to use Bootstrap, but I can use another framework that supports Boostrap.
Thanks in advance. Any suggestions?
Component

Hi, maybe if you could explain how the component work - stating what the elements do, your question would be more clearer
